# Laravel 4.2 eloquent hasMany php empty results to true but false after read?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Here's the class:

```
class EventStepInstance extends Model
{
  //..
  public static function boot()
  {
    self::deleting(function($eventStepInstance) {
        $classname = $eventStepInstance->step->handler;
        if (!$classname || $classname == "default") {
            $classname = 'Focus\Sped\Controller\DefaultFormHandler';
        }

        if (class_exists($classname)) {
            $handler =  App::make($classname);
            $handler->deleteData($eventStepInstance->id);
        }

        return true;
    });

    return parent::boot();
  }


   public function step()
   {
     return $this->belongsTo('Focus\Sped\EventStep', 'event_step_id');
   }


    public function checkCompletion()
    {
      var_export(empty($this->step->classname)); // true
      var_export($this->step->classname);
      var_export(empty($this->step->classname)); // false
    }
}
```

Is the bit that happens in checkCompletion expected behavior? Why would this happen? The only laravel specific function we override is the boot function on both classes and we return the result of parent::boot().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this looks kinda weird for be honest the only thing I think is that it could be that the property is only accessible after reading just like doctrine does, they do this for performance improvements but as far a I know eloquent shouldn't do this